# CSS Div Problem in IE8 - Huge gaps i can't explain

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm really not a CSS guru as you will notice :)
I have a rather simple site, but I just can't see why IE8
adds such huge gaps between the packshots.

http://www.videospielkalender.de/

I'd be very happy if someone can point me in the right direction.
I really searched a long time. I really tried :)

Thanks in advance
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are creating the following structure for a link:

```
<a href="bla">
    <div class="container">
        <a><img/></a>
    </div>
</a>
```

So my first question would be: Why is there a div in your link?
You have to keep into account that a `div` is a block element and the `a` is an inline element. For a good reason, IE doesn't get you with this structure.

Try reshaping your containers to something with less irrelevant css. For example: you could create simple `<div class="container">` elements with the same structure as you have now, but do not explicitly add height and weight to it. HTML can figure these things out by himself.

Answer (score 0):

Without delving too deeply into your code, I believe that there is a bug in IE, which means that you have to allow an extra pixel occasionally, because things will not always fit precisely.

Comment: Well, it's anything but a table.